# proving an inequality by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($\Omega, F, \mu $) be a finite measure space. Suppose $f: \Omega \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ satisfies $0<\int_{\Omega}f^{2} d\mu<\infty$ and $f = 0$ on $\Omega \setminus A$. By getting help from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality Prove that

$$\mu(A)\geq \frac{(\int_{\Omega}f d\mu)^{2}}{\int_{\Omega}f^{2} d\mu}$$

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\int_{\Omega}
|f g| d\mu\leq \sqrt{\int_{\Omega}f^{2} d\mu} \sqrt{\int_{\Omega}g^{2} d\mu}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $g\equiv 1$ on $A$ and $0$ outside $A$. (I'm assuming $A$ is a measurable set.) Additionally $\int_{\Omega} f\,d\mu \le \int_{\Omega}|f|\,d\mu$. That it is a finite measure space assures that $g\in L^2(\mu)$ so that Cauchy-Schwarz is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Since $ f = 0$ on $\Omega\setminus A$, $f = f\cdot 1_A$. So by the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality,

$$\left(\int_\Omega f\, d\mu\right)^2 \le \left(\int_\Omega f^2\, d\mu\right) \left(\int_\Omega 1_A^2 \, d\mu\right) = \left(\int_\Omega f^2 \, d\mu\right) \cdot \mu(A).$$